# How to restrict users in activemq?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am newbie to activemq.I have downloaded latest activemq 5.8 and run the server.I have created queue and sending sample messages using following code:

```
// URL of the JMS server. DEFAULT_BROKER_URL will just mean
    // that JMS server is on localhost
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    // Name of the queue we will be sending messages to
    private static String subject = "TESTQUEUE";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        // Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // JMS messages are sent and received using a Session. We will
        // create here a non-transactional session object. If you want
        // to use transactions you should set the first parameter to 'true'
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Destination represents here our queue 'TESTQUEUE' on the
        // JMS server. You don't have to do anything special on the
        // server to create it, it will be created automatically.
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

        // MessageProducer is used for sending messages (as opposed
        // to MessageConsumer which is used for receiving them)
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        // We will send a small text message saying 'Hello' in Japanese
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("こんにちは");

        // Here we are sending the message!
        producer.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");

        connection.close();
    }
```

I have run above code and queue created successfully.Now i want to restrict user access  in activemq server.I changed the createConnnection method as below

```
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("test","test");
```

Now if i run changed code messages sending to queue successfully.but test user is not there in activemq even connection established.How to restrict this user?

```
<authorizationPlugin>
    <map>
      <authorizationMap>
        <authorizationEntries>
          <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
          <authorizationEntry queue="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users" />
          <authorizationEntry queue="GUEST.>" read="guests" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users" />

          <authorizationEntry queue="TEST.Q" read="guests" write="guests" />

          <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
          <authorizationEntry topic="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users" />
          <authorizationEntry topic="GUEST.>" read="guests" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users" />

          <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="guests,users" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users"/>
        </authorizationEntries>
      </authorizationMap>
    </map>
  </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

In the above file is activemq.xml.Now i want to access queue only certain users only.

How to restrict users in actviemq? what am i need change above activemq.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

See ActiveMQ doc: http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

In activemq.xml :

Define queues you want to create in "destinations" section  . 
You can control privileges by defining groups in the "users" section.
In the "authorizationEntries" section, you can define what groups are allowed to read, write and admin a queue.

Framgent of activemq.xml:

```html
<destinations>    
   <queue physicalName="DEMOQUEUE01" />
   <queue physicalName="DEMOQUEUE02" />
   <queue physicalName="DEMOQUEUE03" />
</destinations> 

<plugins>  
   <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
     <users> 
    <authenticationUser username="admin"       password="admin"       groups="usuarios,users,admins"/>
    <authenticationUser username="system"      password="manager"       groups="usuarios,users,admins"/> 
 
    <authenticationUser username="youruser1" password="password123" groups="GROUP01,DEMOGROUP"/> 
       <authenticationUser username="youruser2" password="password456" groups="GROUP01,OTHERGROUP"/> 
     </users>
   </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
   <authorizationPlugin>
     <map>
    <authorizationMap>
      <authorizationEntries>    
     <authorizationEntry queue = "DEMOQUEUE01" read="admins,GROUP01" write="admins,GROUP01" admin="admins"/>
     <authorizationEntry queue = "DEMOQUEUE02"  read="admins,DEMOGROUP" write="admins"  admin="admins"/>
     <authorizationEntry queue = "DEMOQUEUE03"  read="admins,OTHERGROUP" write="admins,OTHERGROUP"  admin="admins"/>
     
     <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
     <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="usuarios,admins,GROUP01" write="usuarios,admins,GROUP01" admin="usuarios" />
      </authorizationEntries>
    </authorizationMap>
     </map>
   </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Hi. What queue? What language? What question?